# Redirect all URLs to contain 'www' prefix

Tags: url, iis, web-config, redirect

I want to redirect all traffic from

```
https://url
```

to

```
https://www.url
```

How can I write the redirect url?:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Add www prefix">
                     <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                     <action type="Redirect" url="what to put here?" redirectType="Permanent" />
                   </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing like that

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.YOURWEBSITE.com" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can find more [here](https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<rules>
   <rule name="www redirect" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Adjust that to your needs but i think it works.